# Populate control with set of labels

Tags: c#, winforms, label-control

I'm writing a program that get data from the registry and then adds groupboxes to a tabcontrol, and in the groupbox I'd like to create as many label controls (to display the registry info) as many data (key-value pairs) I got.
To do this I made this function:

```
private void AddAllControl()
{
    GroupBox TestGroupBox = new GroupBox();
    TestGroupBox.AutoSize = true;
    TestGroupBox.Text = "valami";
    TestGroupBox.Height = 500;
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        Label TempLabel = new Label();
        TempLabel.Text = i.ToString();
        TempLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + i, 30);
        TempLabel.Show();
        TempLabel.Visible = true;
        TempLabel.Enabled = true;
        TestGroupBox.Controls.Add(TempLabel);               
    }
    tabPage_SandBox.Controls.Add(TestGroupBox);
}
```

This function is processed when a button been pressed. After that The groupbox appear correctly, but only 1 label the first (with text = 0) appear instead of 21 label.
When I stop to debug the program I see all the labels are exists and all the property are correct, however they do not appear.
There must be something that I didn't noticed.
And now my question? What did I wrong?
As you can see I tried both `visible` and `enabled` property but neither of bring me solution.

Comment: Did you already consider to use a `ListView` or `DataGridView` to display your data?    This might be a better solution.

Comment: Set this property before adding control. `TempLabel.AutoSize = true;`. Only 0 is printed because this label is overlapping on other labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set

```
  TempLabel.AutoSize = true;
```

And you have to modify the location a little bit like

```
 TempLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + 10 * i, 30);
```

or I think you want to have the labels one below the other so you have to set the location like

```
 TempLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20+20 * i);
```

Comment: Now I got it. Thx for the help. I forgot that the labels are in a rectangular. Because all the Label had exactly the same size only the first was seen cause the rest were exactly below it. Gosh I'm an idiot... Thx again 4 the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your Labels are a constant size then

```
TestGroupBox.Controls.Add(new Label()
{
    Text = i.ToString(),
    Location = new Point(20 + (i*20), 30),
    Size = new Size(20, 20)
});
```

Would do the trick